# remote connectivity tool like teamviewer for ubuntu server

Tags: remote, remote-management

I have Ubuntu 12.x server edition at office. it is hosted behind multiple wan load balancers. is there any tool like teamviewer that i can use to connect with it from my home?

Comment: Why not use teamviewer? It works fine on Ubuntu.

Comment: @shivams 1) it's overkill if a VNC is available, or if text mode is enough, 2) the connection goes through teamviewer servers, which is a big no-no in security sensitive setups 3) it's not free (in both senses), for commercial use you have to pay for it

Answer (score 3):

VNC if you are speaking about GUI (or x11vnc on the server if you want to connect to a *running* session), there are [several implementations available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=vnc). You have to access the server somehow from the outside, exposing VNC directly to the internet is not recommended. For a secure tunnel consider OpenVPN. Or for lesser effort, tunnel VNC through ssh ([ssvnc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ssvnc) is good for this).

If you are speaking about text only access, nothing beats plain old ssh or [mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu).

In short, there are many possibilities and it depends on your network accessibility.

Comment: Problem is that I dont have access to the DSL Routers as they are in lock-down mode by the providers. so I cannot use port forward to use SSH or other service. Using teamviewer type tool is easier as i dont have to look for public ip or port forward but i guess it requires gui + it have limitations of session and sometimes it blocks me saying suspected commercial usage :OI have Ubuntu server edition which dont have GUI , its CLI only. So is there any tool I can install on my server and can access via text? only text base access is required like ssh.

Comment: @SyedJahanzaib Then it's not about remote connectivity tools, but about network access. Depending on what the routers block, I'd suggest to install [miredo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/miredo) and then use ssh/VNC through this connection. Just be aware that the IP address would change periodically.